# Why am I getting the 'Unknown option 'googleCalendarApiKey'' error in Fullcalendar in Shopify?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to use Fullcalendar in my shopify store.
I would like to display Google Calendar events on the calendar displayed in Fullcalendar, but when I follow the documentation, I get the following console error below.

> Unknown option 'googleCalendarApiKey'

index.global.js is stored in the assets folder and called in .
Is there any problem with this?

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.7/main.min.css">
    <script src="{{'index.global.js' | asset_url}}" async></script>
    <script>

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          googleCalendarApiKey: '<MY API KEY>',
          eventSources: [
            {
              googleCalendarId: 'sample@group.calendar.google.com',
              display: 'background',
              className: 'gcal-event'
            }, {
              googleCalendarId: 'ja.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
              display: 'background',
              className: 'gcal-event'
            }
          ],
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
          headerToolbar: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev,today,next'
          },
          locale: 'en',
          fixedWeekCount: false,
          contentHeight: 300,
          aspectRatio: 1
        });

        calendar.render();

      });
    </script>
```

Comment: This code is littered with basic JS syntax errors (e.g. `.`  in places where there shouldn't be, things seemingly repeated for no reason) which makes it impossible for us to reproduce the specific error you're talking about. Fix those, post it again, and we'll then see if there's actually a real issue or not. Please always ensure you post a [mre] of the issue - see also [ask]. If you provide code, always copy/paste it rather than re-typing or anything, to avoid introducing mistakes which don't exist in the original. Thanks.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar#getting-set-up: _"You must include the google-calendar plugin. [...] Alternatively, you can use a global bundle"_ - the global bundle you used does not appear to actually include that plugin? https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.7/README.md

Comment: @ADyson
Thank you!
Somehow I have made a lot of mistakes when copying and pasting. I really don't know how come the `.` .

The code has been fixed anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Now I ran your code with fullCalendar 5.10.1, and can't reproduce the error - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/wvYNKyJ . Are you sure that a) you're using fullCalendar 5 (as per your tag), and b) you don't have an issue like CBroe suggested, with packages missing from your bundle? According to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/initialize-globals though, in v5 the google calendar package is included in the default bundle. In v6 (as per Cbroe's comment and link) it isn't.